# Remote Methods of inherited models not showing up in loopback explorer

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have inherited a model in loopback like this-

```
{
    "name": "MyModel",
    "base": "AnotherModel",
    "idInjection": false,
    "properties": {
      "value": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "display": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": []
}
```

While I am able to call all the remote methods of `AnotherModel` from my `MyModel.js` file. But, the remote methods of `AnotherModel` are not showing up on my explorer. How to get all the remote methods of my inherited model to show up in explorer?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that happens is that, when you called `AnotherModel.remoteMethod`, it only registered that remote method for that model and not the models that are based of this. To call it for all models that are based of AnotherModel you can do this:

```js
var originalSetup = AnotherModel.setup;
AnotherModel.setup = function() { // this will be called everytime a 
  // model is extended from this model.

  originalSetup.apply(this, arguments); // This is necessary if your 
  // AnotherModel is based of another model, like PersistedModel.

  this.remoteMethod('yourMethod', {
    ..
  });
};
```

I learnt this from [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extending+built-in+models#Extendingbuilt-inmodels-Settingupacustommodel) and also checking how persistedModel has all it's remote method in all models that are based of it.

Also make sure the base model is public [due to this issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1130).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setup()` to "expose" AnotherModels' functions. 
http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Extending-built-in-models.html#setting-up-a-custom-model
then in the setup section add your remote methods as described here: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods#example

Here is the example: (it can also apply to static functions)

```js
// AnotherModel.js
module.exports = function (AnotherModel) {
    ...
    // suppose you have two functions to inherit 'function1' and 'function2'
    AnotherModel.prototype.function1 = function() {...}
    AnotherModel.function2 = function() {...}
    // The loopback.Model.extend() function calls setup() 
    // so code you put in setup() will automatically get 
    // executed when the model is created.  
    var originalSetup = AnotherMoldel.setup;
    AnotherMoldel.setup = function() {
        // call the original setup!
        originalSetup.apply(this, arguments);
        // 'this' will points to MyModel during MyModel setup
        // first param should match with function name
        this.remoteMethod('function1', {
            accepts: {...}, 
            returns: {...}, 
            http: {...}});
        this.remoteMethod('function2', {
            accepts: {...}, 
            returns: {...}, 
            http: {...}});
    }
}
```

It will show up in the API explorer.

I hope it helps, please let me know if you found another solution! (as this post is more than a year old)

Cheers